# problema al mostar información de json a través de jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

tengo este codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<!---->
<body>
    <h1>Tutorial json-jquery</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <input type="button" id="lista" value="mostrar lista">
    <div id="contenedor">
        <ul class="contenedorlista">

        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#lista").click(function(){
                   $.getJSON("index.php", function(data){
                       if(data){
                           $.each(data,function(key,value){
                               $("#contenedorlista").append("<li>el id de profesor"+value.numeroID+"y su nombre es"+value.nombre+""+value.apellido+"</li>");
                           });
                       }
                   });
               });
           });
    </script>
</body>
```

y tengo un archivo en la misma carpeta llamado "index.php" que posee la matriz que luego convierto a json

```
<?php
$profesor = array(
        array(
            "numeroID" => "3",
            "nombre" => "jorge",
            "apellido" => "mochon",
            "especialidad" => array(
                                    "imagen",
                                    "video")
        ),
        array(
            "numeroID" => "120",
            "nombre" => "luis",
            "apellido" => "bergonza",
            "especialidad" => array(
                                    "desarrollo",
                                    "aplicaciones",
                                    "mobiles")
        )
    );
    header('Content-type:application/json');
        echo json_encode($profesor);
?>
```

el problema viene cuando cargo la pagina y le doy click al boton para que me pinte los datos en la lista desordenada y es que no lo hace, en la consola del nav me indica esto :

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Failed to load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/practicaJson/ajaxboton/index.php: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension
```

no se que error es, si es que especifique mal el archivo .php

Comment: ¿Estás cargando directamente la página del sistema de archivos o la estás sirviendo a través de un servidor web?

Comment: Tienes problema de origen cruzado quizas agregando cabeceras CORS se solucione

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese error lo da porque estás haciendo referencia a un archivo php local (`C:/xampp/htdocs/practicaJson/ajaxboton/index.php`). ¿Estás utilizando algún IDE en concreto?

Tienes dos opciones:

1.- Hacer correr un servidor en tu máquina local y ejecutar ahí tu código.
2.- Subir el código a un servidor y probar ahí.

Más [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)